# Why does <input type="number"> disappear after I pressed other buttons

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am writing a website that creates diary card. When I pressed the "create diary" button the first time, a small div becomes visible, and it looks like this:
[image]
Here's the html code:

```
<div id="newDiary">
  <label for="tag-detail">choose a tag</label>
  <select id="tag-detail">
    <option value="school">school</option>
    <option value="social">social</option>
    <option value="club">club</option>
    <option value="others">others</option>
  </select>
  <label for="mood-detail">choose a mood</label>
  <select id="mood-detail">
    <option value="happy">happy</option>
    <option value="mad">mad</option>
    <option value="sad">sad</option>
    <option value="others">others</option>
  </select>
  <div id="date-detail">
    <label for="year"></label>
    <input type="number" name="year" id="year"></input>
    <label for="month"></label>
    <input type="number" id="month" name="month"></input>
    <label for="day"></label>
    <input type="number" id="day" name="day"></input
  </div>
  <textarea id="diaryContent"></textarea
  <input type="file" id="diaryPicture"></input>
  <button id="saveDiary1">save</button>
  <button id="cancel">cancel</button>
</div>
```

However, when I pressed "cancel" button and pressed the "create diary" button again, the date part disappear.It looks like this:
[image]
The other parts work fine.
I open the console and notice that the `<input>` and `<label>` element disappear. Why is it happening?
Here's my js code(I deleted some code that is not related to the problem):

```
function showDiaryDetail(isNew,original_tag,original_mood,original_date,original_description) {//works only the first time
  newDiaryTemplate.style.display = "block";
  const tag=document.querySelector("#tag-detail");
  const mood = document.querySelector("#mood-detail");
  const date=document.querySelector("#date-detail");
  const year=document.querySelector(`input[name="year"]`);
  const month=document.querySelector(`input[name="month"]`);
  const day=document.querySelector(`input[name="day"]`);
  const content=document.querySelector("#diaryContent");
  const img=document.querySelector("#diaryPicture");
  const save=document.querySelector("#saveDiary1");
  const cancel=document.querySelector("#cancel");
  let week;
  if(isNew===true){
    let time=new Date();
    year.value=time.getFullYear();
    month.value=time.getMonth()+1;
    day.value=time.getDate();
    week=time.getDay();
  }
  if(!cancelCreate){
    cancelCreate=true;
    cancel.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      newDiaryTemplate.style.display = "none";
      tag.value = "";
      mood.value="";
      date.textContent="";
      year.value=new Date().getFullYear();
      month.value=new Date().getMonth()+1;
      day.value=new Date().getDate();
      content.value="";
    });
  }
}
```

Also, `e.preventDefault` doesn't work for me.
I want to know why this happens and how to fix it. Thanks!
edit:
here's where I call the showDiaryDetail() (the addDiaryButton is the create diary button metioned above):

```
function setupEventListeners() {
  const addDiaryButton = document.querySelector("#addDiary");
  addDiaryButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    btn="create";
    showDiaryDetail(true,"","","","");
  });
}
```

Comment: It'll be difficult to say without context *(e.g., `cancelCreate` appears to be a global and there's no way to know what else might affect it or where it's used)*. It might help to make this into an executable snippet to avoid guessing.

Comment: 3 missing part here,  how you call ´showDiaryDetail´ func?, where are cancel and  save buttons click handler?

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL thanks for reminding. I edit my post! And the cancel button click handler is at the buttom of showDiaryDetail() func. I deleted the save button click handler because I haven't tested that yet.

Comment: `newDiaryTemplate.style.display = "none";` probably because of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// This line clear all children
date.textContent="";
```

`year.value=time.getFullYear();` You are getting error on this line.

--

```
 if(!cancelCreate){
        cancelCreate=true;
        cancel.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          newDiaryTemplate.style.display = "none";
          tag.value = "";
          mood.value="";
          // This line clear all children
          date.textContent="";
          year.value=new Date().getFullYear();
          month.value=new Date().getMonth()+1;
          day.value=new Date().getDate();
          content.value="";
        });
      }
```

```js
        var cancelCreate;
    function showDiaryDetail(isNew,original_tag,original_mood,original_date,original_description) {//works only the first time
        newDiaryTemplate =  document.getElementById('newDiaryTemplate')
        newDiaryTemplate.style.display = "block";
        const tag=document.querySelector("#tag-detail");
        const mood = document.querySelector("#mood-detail");
        const date=document.querySelector("#date-detail");
        const year=document.querySelector(`input[name="year"]`);
        const month=document.querySelector(`input[name="month"]`);
        const day=document.querySelector(`input[name="day"]`);
        const content=document.querySelector("#diaryContent");
        const img=document.querySelector("#diaryPicture");
        const save=document.querySelector("#saveDiary1");
        const cancel=document.querySelector("#cancel");
        let week;
        if(isNew===true){
          let time=new Date();
          year.value=time.getFullYear();
          month.value=time.getMonth()+1;
          day.value=time.getDate();
          week=time.getDay();
        }
        if(!cancelCreate){
          cancelCreate=true;
          cancel.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            newDiaryTemplate.style.display = "none";
            tag.value = "";
            mood.value="";
            // textContent 
            // date.textContent="";
            year.value=new Date().getFullYear();
            month.value=new Date().getMonth()+1;
            day.value=new Date().getDate();
            content.value="";
          });
        }
      }
      function setupEventListeners() {
  const addDiaryButton = document.querySelector("#addDiary");
  addDiaryButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    btn="create";
    showDiaryDetail(true,"","","","");
  });
}
window.onload = ()=>{
    setupEventListeners()

}
```

```html
<div id="newDiary">
    <label for="tag-detail">choose a tag</label>
    <select id="tag-detail">
      <option value="school">school</option>
      <option value="social">social</option>
      <option value="club">club</option>
      <option value="others">others</option>
    </select>
    <label for="mood-detail">choose a mood</label>
    <select id="mood-detail">
      <option value="happy">happy</option>
      <option value="mad">mad</option>
      <option value="sad">sad</option>
      <option value="others">others</option>
    </select>
    <div id="date-detail">
      <label for="year"></label>
      <input type="number" name="year" id="year"></input>
      <label for="month"></label>
      <input type="number" id="month" name="month"></input>
      <label for="day"></label>
      <input type="number" id="day" name="day"></input>
    </div>
    <textarea id="diaryContent"></textarea>
    <input type="file" id="diaryPicture"></input>
    <button id="addDiary">save</button>
    <button id="cancel">cancel</button>
    <div id="newDiaryTemplate"></div>
```